# Spring 4.1.4 and Jackson 2.5, annotation driven setup not converting REST responses to JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I coming back to Spring after spending 5 years doing other things. I have an initial projects which is designed to provide a HTTP REST service that returns JSON.

My problem is that I cannot get the service to convert the response to JSON. Instead I get errors like this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [hello]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/hello] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:205) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
...
```

My web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>au.com.abc.service</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>fxServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>au.com.abc.controller</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fxServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

And my Controller class looks like this:

```
@RestController
public class FXRESTController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public Map<String,Object> rootContextHandler() {
    Map<String,Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("X", "abc");
    return data;
}
}
```

It really cannot get any simpler. I've been passing the request header Accept='application/json', but it's still not working. I have had this type of thing working in the past, but I don't have that code anymore. I can also see this in the logs:

```
... Invoking request handler method: public java.util.Map au.com.abc.controller.FXRESTController.rootContextHandler()
... Service responding
... Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'hello'
... Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'hello'; URL [hello]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'fxServlet'
... Added model object 'X' of type [java.lang.String] to request in view with name 'hello'
... Error rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'hello'; URL [hello]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'fxServlet'
```

Which suggests to me that it's trying to render a JSTL view. Why - I don't know considering I've asked for JSON.

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

I've read a ton of blogs and so far I cannot see any differences between what they have done and what I've done.

Oh and here are my gradle resolved dependencies:

[image]

Comment: Does your controller *look like that* or is that your actual controller...

Comment: Thats a cutnpaste of the code from the controller minus the imports, etc.

Comment: You seem to only have a controller, that doesn't do anything for enabling JSON. You have to have a `@Configuration` annotated class which is also annotated with `@EnableWebMvc` to have automatic JSON conversion enabled. You are running with the `DispatcherServlet` defaults which are very basic.

Comment: Ahhhh, let me try that, I didn't pick up on that :-(

Comment: Your a LEGEND ! That worked. Thanks so much.

Comment: Cut n paste that as an answer so can close please.

Comment: I also recommend switching over to Spring Boot. It provides sensible, overrideable defaults for nearly everything and lets you package as a standalone executable jar (which makes deployment easier) or a war that doesn't need manual `web.xml` or annotation config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have a controller, that doesn't do anything for enabling JSON.

You have to have a `@Configuration` annotated class which is also annotated with [`@EnableWebMvc`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) to have automatic JSON conversion enabled. See also [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) section of the reference guide.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfiguration {}
```

You are running with the [`DispatcherServlet` defaults](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet-config) which are very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ResponseBody`.
ALso donot direct all request to spring

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fxServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

ALways better to add a layer like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fxServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webapp/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

FOr a given project only following request will be directed to spring

```
http://localhost:8080/Proj/app/hello
```

Other request can be handled different..thus you can handle request in a different way and not dependent on spring..like

```
http://localhost:8080/Proj/servlethandler
```

The above request will not go to spring and can be intercepted by a servlet etc..